# python-memcache memcached -- I installed on centos virtualbox but it get/set never seem to work

Tags: memcached, python-memcached

I'm using python. I did a yum install memcached followed by a easy_install python-memcached

I used the simple test program from the Help(memcache). When I wasn't getting the proper answers I threw in some print statements:

```
[~/test]$  cat m2.py
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)

x = mc.set("some_key", "Some value")
print 'Just set a key and value into the cache (suposedly)'

value = mc.get("some_key")
print 'Just retrieved that value from the cache using the key'

print 'X %s' % x

print 'Value %s' % value    

[~/test]$  python m2.py
Just set a key and value into the cache (suposedly)
Just retrieved that value from the cache using the key
X 0
Value None
[~/test]$
```

The question now is, what have I failed to do in my installation?  It appears to be working from an API perspective but it fails to put anything into the memcache share area.
I'm using a virtualbox vm running centos
    [~]# cat /proc/version
    Linux version 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.i686 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc     version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu May 16 18:12:13 UTC 2013

Is there a daemon that is supposed to be running?  I don't see an obvious named one when I do a ps.

I tried to get pylibmc installed on my vm but was unable to find a working installation so for now will see if I can get the above stuff working first.

I discovered if i ran straight from the python console GUI i get a bit more output if I set debug=1

```
>>> mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1)
>>> mc.stats
{}
>>> mc.set('test','value')
MemCached: MemCache: inet:127.0.0.1:11211: connect: Connection     refused.  Marking dead.
0
>>> mc.get('test')
MemCached: MemCache: inet:127.0.0.1:11211: connect: Connection refused.  Marking dead.
```

When I try to use per the example telnet to connect to the port i get a connection refused:

```
[root@~]# telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@~]#
```

I tried the instructions I found on the net for configuring telnet so localhost wouldn't be disabled:
    vi /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
    service telnet
    {
    flags = REUSE
    socket_type = stream 
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
    log_on_failure += USERID
    disable = no
    }

And then ran the commands to restart the service(s):

```
service iptables stop
service xinetd stop
service iptables start
service xinetd start
service iptables stop
```

I ran with both cases (iptables started and stopped) but it has no effect. So I am out of ideas.  What do I need to do to make it so the PORT will be allowed? if that is the problem?
Or is there a memcached service that needs to be running that needs to open up the port ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is what it took to get it working:  ( a series of manual steps )

```
1) su -
   cd /var/run
   mkdir memcached # this was missing
```

In the memcached file I added "-l 127.0.0.1" to the OPTIONS statement.  It's apparently a listen option.  Do this for steps 2 & 3.  I'm not certain which file is actually used at runtime.

```
2) cd /etc/sysconfig
   cp memcached memcached.old
   vi memcached

3) cd /etc/init.d
   cp memcached memcached.old
   vi memcached
```

4) Try some commands to see if the server starts now

```
/etc/init.d/memcached start
/etc/init.d/memcached status
/etc/init.d/memcached stop
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

I tried opening a browser, but it never seemed to actually display anything so I don't really know how valid this approach is.  I'm not running apache or anything like this so perhaps its not relevant to my cause.  Perhaps I would have to supply a ?key=blah or something.

```
5)  http://127.0.0.1:11211
```

6) Now it should be ready to go.  If one runs the test shown with the following it should work.  At least it did for me.  doing the help(memcache) will display a simple program.  just paste that in and it should work just fine.

```
[~]$ python
>>> import memcache
>>> help(memcache)
```

Comment: Adding the following command in a root session seems to help as well `chkconfig memcached on`  . Doing that will make it so the memcached service runs at the next server bootup automatically.